# Good Average of Speed/Memory Efficiency Method to Create a Set In C?:

Tags: c, data-structures, set

Let's say that I am streaming non-empty strings (char[]/char*s) into my program. I would like to create a set of them. That is, for any element a in set S, a is unique in S.

I have thought to approach this in a few ways, but have run into issues.

If I knew the amount of items n I would be reading, I could just create a hash table, with all elements beginning as null, of the same size and if there was a collision, do not insert it into that table. When the insertions are done, I would iterate through the array of the hashtable, counting non-null values, size, and then create an array of that size, and then copy all the values to it.

I could use just use a single array and resize it before an element is added, using a search algorithm to check to see if an element already exists before resizing/adding it.

I realize the second method would work, but because the elements may not be sorted, could also take a very long time for large inputs because of choice of search algorithm and resizing, regardless.

Any input would be appreciated. Please feel free to ask questions in the comment box below if you need further information. Libraries would be very helpful! (Google searching "Sets in C" and similar things doesn't help very much.)

Comment: I did not understand your question, why don't you use one of the well known hash sets algorithms? what *exactly* do you want to do when you detect a collision?

Comment: I do NOT want it to be added to the set.

A set is defined as containing an element at MOST 1 times. If two or more separate elements are considered equal, only one of them can be contained in the set.

Comment: a collision in a hash set may occur even if elements are different, because they are hashed to the same value. are you trying to achieve a map that says either or not an element was encountered before?

Comment: You could have a collision in your hash table even if they are unique strings. This is not a good way to implement set functionality.   EDIT: I don't mean to say that a hash table is not a good way to implement a set. I just mean that checking for collisions is not a good way to determine that a string is not unique.

Comment: I understand that. I do not want a second object added to the set ONLY IF another EQUAL object already exists in the set. If the object which  the hash functions points to is not equal to the object being inserted, then I would use collision resolution until I either found an empty table entry and insert the element or a copy of the current element and do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hash table can work even if you didn't know the size of the number of elements that you are going to be inserting ... you would simply define you hash table to use "buckets" (i.e., each position is actually a linked list of elements that hash to the same value), and you would search through each "bucket" to make sure that each element has not already been inserted into the hash-table.  The key to avoiding large "buckets" to search through would be a good hash algorithm.

You can also, if you can define a weak ordering of your objects, use a binary search tree.  Then if !(A < B) and !(B < A), it can be assumed A == B, and you would therefore not insert any additional iterations of that object into the tree, which again would define a set.

While I know you're using C, consider the fact that in the C++ STL, `std::set` uses a RB-tree (red-black tree which is a balanced binary search tree), and `std::unordered_set` uses a hash-table.

Using an array is a bad idea ... resizing operations will take a long time, where-as insertions into a tree can be done in O(log N) time, and for a hash-table, ammortized O(1).

Comment: This is a wonderful answer, as it provides multiple options.
I feel that I will be opting away from the hash table quite as described. Because there is an arbitrary numbers of elements, it would be impossible to create an appropriately sized hash-table so that the buckets would not be painfully large with linear search-time. This gave me some ideas for new data structures, actually. Even if these ideas do not work, then I have the ideas from STL to check out. Thank you so much!